# JOIN query taking long time and creating issue "converting HEAP to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, myisam

My query like below. here I used join query to take data. can u pls suggest how can I solve  "converting HEAP to MyISAM" issue.
[image]
[image]

Can I use subquery here to update it? pls suggest how can I.

Here I have joined users table to check user is exist or not. can I refine it without join so that  "converting HEAP to MyISAM" can solve.

Oh one more sometimes I will not check with specific user_id. like here I have added user_id = 16082

```
SELECT `user_point_logs`.`id`, 
   `user_point_logs`.`user_id`, 
   `user_point_logs`.`point_get_id`, 
   `user_point_logs`.`point`, 
   `user_point_logs`.`expire_date`, 
   `user_point_logs`.`point`  AS `sum_point`, 

   IF(sum(`user_point_used_logs`.`point`) IS NULL, 0, sum(`user_point_used_logs`.`point`)) AS `minus` 

   FROM   `user_point_logs` 

     JOIN `users` ON ( `users`.`id` = `user_point_logs`.`user_id` ) 

     LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
              FROM   user_point_used_logs 
              WHERE  user_point_log_id NOT IN (
                                                     SELECT DISTINCT return_id 
                                               FROM   user_point_logs 
                                               WHERE  return_id IS NOT NULL 
                                                      AND user_id = 16082
                                                              )
                  ) 
    AS user_point_used_logs
      ON ( `user_point_logs`.`id` = `user_point_used_logs`.`user_point_log_used_id` ) 

    WHERE  expire_date >= 1563980400 

   AND `user_point_logs`.`point` >= 0 

   AND `users`.`id` IS NOT NULL 

   AND ( `user_point_logs`.`return_id` = 0 
          OR `user_point_logs`.`return_id` IS NULL ) 

   AND `user_point_logs`.`user_id` = '16082' 

   GROUP  BY `user_point_logs`.`id` 
   ORDER  BY `user_point_logs`.`expire_date` ASC
```

[**DB FIDDLE HERE WITH STRUCTURE**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pSYWaJdyjKJxWSywvExLfy/2)

[image: error image]

Comment: share your `explain` execution plan as well

Comment: @James I am not sure how can I solve this issue. I can remove "users" table join query. but others join query how to refine I am not getting how to do.

Comment: In the beginning of your query add EXPLAIN SELCT ..... then share the result

Comment: Can you add your table create statements since there are unnecessary where clause exists. And better to understand your index and other column datatypes

Comment: Thanks for you detailed info. It seems user table is missing?

Comment: @James Yeah I just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly try this, If it works... will optimize further by adding composite index.

```
SELECT 
    upl.id,
    upl.user_id,
    upl.point_get_id,
    upl.point,
    upl.expire_date,
    upl.point AS sum_point,
    coalesce(SUM(upl.point),0) AS minus -- changed from complex to readable
FROM user_point_logs upl
JOIN users u ON upl.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (select supul.user_point_log_used_id from user_point_used_logs supul
left join user_point_logs supl on supul.user_point_log_id=supl.return_id and supl.return_id is null and supl.user_id = 16082) AS upul 
ON upl.id=upul.user_point_log_used_id

WHERE
upl.user_id = 16082 and coalesce(upl.return_id,0)= 0 
and upl.expire_date >= 1563980400 -- tip: if its unix timestamp change the datatype and if possible use range between dates
        #AND upl.point >= 0 -- since its NN by default removing this condition
        #AND u.id IS NOT NULL -- removed since the inner join matches not null
GROUP BY upl.id
ORDER BY upl.expire_date ASC;
```

**Edit:**

Try adding index in the column `return_id` on the table `user_point_logs`.
Since this column is used in join on derived query.
Or use composite index with `user_id and return_id`

Comment: thanks for ur help. it looks improved. is there any way improve more . it will be good . https://i.imgur.com/bhdeS0b.jpg

Comment: Okay, so is the result is what you needed?

Comment: Yeah looks like improved. as u told u can optimize more so u can try. that will be more appreciable

Comment: **Edited** if it works we can optimize further in the `where` clause

Answer (score 1):

Indexes:

```
user_point_logs:  (user_id, expire_date)
user_point_logs:  (user_id, return_id)
```

`OR` is hard to optimize.  Decide on only one way to say whatever is being said here, then get rid of the `OR`:

```
   AND (     `user_point_logs`.`return_id` = 0 
          OR `user_point_logs`.`return_id` IS NULL )
```

`DISTINCT` is redundant:

```
NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ... )
```

Change

```
IF(sum(`user_point_used_logs`.`point`) IS NULL, 0,
   sum(`user_point_used_logs`.`point`)) AS `minus`
```

to

```
COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM(point) FROM   user_point_used_logs ... ), 0)  AS minus
```

and toss `LEFT JOIN (SELECT *     FROM   user_point_used_logs ... )`

Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is a key, the second of these is redundant and can be `DROPped`:

```
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE;
```

After all that, we may need another pass to further simplify and optimize it.